# Can feature importance be measured in machine learning models by selectively removing predictor variables?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, importance

In addition to techniques like measuring permutation importance, could feature importance be estimated by sequentially removing predictor variables from the training data, rerunning the model, and then comparing the prediction error on the validation data to the full model?

Comment: Yes? But I believe you'd need to compute the error for all 2^N (N = number of features) combinations of features. Some sequential procedure (ex: some step-wise regression) could give biased results. 2^N runs could be expensive...

Comment: @Cam.Davidson.Pilon Yes, good point, you'd have to be selective when it comes to choosing which variables to remove. For example, in a model with a lot of binary 0/1 predictors the high frequency predictors might be higher priority.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102850/feature-selection-permutation-test-vs-deleting-a-variable

Comment: @astel Thanks, this is helpful!